# Custom login form won't show any error message

Tags: magento-1.9

I am using custom login form in my magento site. I below mention my custom code

```
    <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('customer.form.login.extra')?>
            <div class="market_place_login_ctrl">
                <form action="<?php echo Mage::getBaseUrl();?>customer/account/loginPost/" method="post" id="login-form" class="market_place_login_ctrl">
                            <?php echo $this->getBlockHtml('formkey'); ?>
                             <div class="col-md-5">
                                <div class="row">
                                    <input type="text" name="login[username]" placeholder="Your Email ID (username)" value="<?php echo $this->escapeHtml($this->getUsername()) ?>" id="email" class="input-text required-entry validate-email" title="<?php echo $this->__('Email Address') ?>" />
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-md-5">
                                <div class="row">
                                    <input type="password" name="login[password]" placeholder="Password" class="input-text required-entry validate-password" id="pass" title="<?php echo $this->__('Password') ?>" />
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class=" col-md-2">
                                <div class="row">
                                <button type="submit" class="button" title="<?php echo $this->__('Login') ?>" name="send" id="send2"><span ><span><?php echo $this->__('Login') ?></span></span></button>
                                </div>
                           </div>
                           <a href="<?php echo Mage::getUrl('customer/account/forgotpassword') ?>">Forgot password?</a>

                             <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('form.additional.info'); ?>
                </form>     
            </div>   



    <script type="text/javascript">
    //<![CDATA[
        var dataForm = new VarienForm('login-form', true);
    //]]>
    </script>
```

But my problem is if customer successfully logged in it redirect to customer account else wrong username or wrong password it won't display any error message. it just reload the page. How i fix it?

Answer (score 1):

You are not echoing message block in your custom login phtml file. So put the message block inside login phtml will resolve this issue.

Put this code just above the form declaration

```
  <?php echo $this->getMessagesBlock()->toHtml() ?>
  <form>
      ....
  </form>
```

Comment: if i use this it won't throw any error. success login my account page show error useername and password

Comment: @LearningMagento  you need to put that code in the template file where you need to show messages. If you put this in login phtml file, you can see messages only if login fails and you are then redirecting to your same custom login page. (here i assume you are using your controller to set messages). If you successfully logged in, you may redirected to another page. if you show success message, then you should put the same code in that template file.

Comment: actually i m using default login file in different page

Comment: default login phtml file is `customer/form/login.phtml` and it does hold that code in that file already.

Comment: but it won't throw any error

Comment: @LearningMagento not sure. This is what we can provide you about your question. If you need further assistance, you need to update your question with more debug details.